# "No such column" error during deletion of a record in Django admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.5, django-1.4

I have following model (`models.py`) in my Django project:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class ArgumentElement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    elementType = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='ArgumentElement_Topic')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.contents

class ArgumentElementConnection(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sourceId = models.ForeignKey(ArgumentElement, related_name='connection_source')
    targetId = models.ForeignKey(ArgumentElement, related_name='connection_target')
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='ArgumentElementConnection_Topic')
    connectionType = models.CharField(max_length=7)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

I add all three models to the admin (`admin.py`):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from history_site.opinions.models import ArgumentElement, ArgumentElementConnection, Topic

admin.site.register(ArgumentElement, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(ArgumentElementConnection, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Topic, admin.ModelAdmin)
```

When I create an instance of `Topic` and then try to delete it in the  Admin, I get the error `no such column: opinions_argumentelement.topic_id`.

What's wrong with my `models.py`?

Comment: Are you also creating the instance using the Admin? And that goes OK?

Comment: Yes, creation seems to work (I get a success message and the newly created instance appears in the list).

Comment: What is you DB engine ? Does it support referential integrity constraints ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I'm using the built-in SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that AutoFields using the sqllite3 backend don't [increment properly](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10164). Is there any reason you are including the line `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` ? If you leave it out, an auto-increment primary key field will be automatically added and is more likely to be correctly created. Try deleting that line and creating a new sqllite database file.